# Div positioning in CSS alters body positioning?

Tags: html, css

**JSFiddle available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dmaymo3m/).**

I am writing an HTML page with nothing else in its body than a simple div.
Without CSS, the div has 100% of window width and about 20% of window height (actually max body height), and is stuck to the window borders. I want it to be centered horizontally and a bit detached vertically, so I applied 100% width and 100% height to html and body tags, and I also applied auto left and right margins to the actual div, + 125px top margin.

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#div {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 125px;
}
```

The problem now is that the page can be scrolled. When highlighting the borders of the elements in the page, you can see that the body element has moved with the div 125px downwards, thus allowing a 125px scrolling. The div is still stuck to the top border of the body, but 125px away from the top border of  the window.
To fix the problem, I had to add `position: fixed;` to the body rules. Then, the body was stuck to the window borders, and the div was 125px away from the top border of the body.

But still, why do positionning a div inside of the body also repositions the whole body ?

**EDIT:** The div id is #prompt in the provided JSFiddle.

**2ND EDIT:** The original question actually was :
Why do I get [this](http://puu.sh/cLtwv/8b9c117670.png) instead of getting [this](http://puu.sh/cLtzq/e12c99d22f.png) ? *(links are pictures)*
WHY is the BODY block actually MOVED by a DIV CSS rule ?
The answer maybe that I'm using Bootstrap and it doesn't like that I override rules for `html` and `body` tags.
See the [marked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851851/div-positioning-in-css-alters-body-positioning/26852077#26852077) just below.

*TL;DR*, you may use `!important` declarations in CSS to properly override `body` and `html` rules.

Comment: in which part u find error but it works fine in fiddle

Comment: My problem was to remove the scrollbar, but it's solved. The real question is : why does a 125px top margin rule in a div CSS moves the body 125px away from the top border of the window, instead of moving the actual div ? (you can see that by using your browser's element inspector/examiner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited Answer:

I added a bootstrap container and some CSS to the html and body elements and this seemed to work.

Fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/tzhben/byye4eop/1/

**CSS:**

```
body {
  background-color: #EDF;
}
html, body {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
     <div id="prompt">
        <p class="well">Please login to continue.</p>
          <form action="index.php" method="post">
             <div id="pwd-box" class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
             </div>
          </form>
     </div>
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</body>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, it does. But the question remains : if you use your browser's element inspector/examiner (I don't know what it's called in English), you can clearly see that the body is 125px away from the top border of the window, while the 125px top margin rule is in the div CSS. Why is that ?

Comment: Could it be because you're using "margin-top" rather than "padding-top"?  How far down do you want your login box to be?  I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: My CSS says this : `#div { margin-top: 125px;}`. I think everyone here would agree that this line should move the div 125px downwards, away from the top border of the body block. But this is not the case, it actually moves the body block 125px downwards, and keeps the div stuck to its top border. You can see this with your browser's element inspector. And THIS is what I'm trying to understand. :/ For a closer look, what it does : http://puu.sh/cLtwv/8b9c117670.png ; and what it should do : http://puu.sh/cLtzq/e12c99d22f.png . How to explain this ?

Comment: Ok I see what you mean now.  The body itself is pushed down 125px.  I will investigate and hopefully produce a fiddle.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this may help. :) But do you have any idea why a div CSS rule also affected the position of the body ?

Comment: Yeah this might be something like that. I didn't think of it when overriding html and body rules. Seems the `!important` declaration fixed it. Thank you again. :)

Comment: whoops was just going to edit my comment and ended up deleting it... either way, glad I could help qreon.

Comment: For those who missed it : the problem probably came from overriding the CSS of body and html tags, already defined by Bootstrap. `!important` seems to have fixed it. I'm going to edit OP for that.

Answer (score 3):

Your current styling creates a height of 100% for the html tag + 125px for the margin, which creates an vertical scroll overflow. This is because you set your html tag css to `height: 100%;`, once removing that line from your css, the positioning of the div no longer affects the scrolling of the page, which is what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/dmaymo3m/1/

Comment: I don't get it, why does a 125px top margin in a div : 1) applies to the body, 2) does not apply to the actual div, which is stuck to the top border of the div ?

Comment: I mean, if you use your browser's element inspector/examiner (I don't know what it's called in English), you can clearly see that the body is 125px away from the top border of the window, while the 125px top margin rule is in the div CSS. Why is that ?